# How to finish several SingleInstance Activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, back-stack

I have several activities with launchMode SingleInstance.  On log out i want to finish all activities  and open launchScreen.

```
val intent = Intent(context, LauncherActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
(context as AppCompatActivity).finishAffinity()
context.startActivity(intent)
```

However if i press back at Launcher activity i am forwarded to previously launched activities with singleInstance mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATE 11/1/2018:

I've tested multiple approach to deal with it such as event propagation, intent flags, counting activity instances, etc. There is some weird scenarios such as starting multiple `singleInstance` activities sequentially. In this case, middle activities doesn't start at all (`onCreate` method isn't called) and after pressing back button, they'll be started. Therefore no one of the prior approaches works! As the issue is a bit strange, I tried to solve it using a bit strange way.

We maintain the logout state in a singleton object called `LogoutHandler`. It cooperates with a class `LogoutAwareActivity` which is inherited by all activities except `LoginActivity` because it should not be affected by logout mechanism. When the logout occurs, a flag is set in the `LogoutHandler` until the last child of `LogoutAwareActivity` has finished then clears the flag.

Here is an implementation of that:

**LogoutHandler:**

```
import java.util.*

object LogoutHandler {

    private var isLogout = false
    private var timerWatchDog: TimerWatchDog? = null

    fun isLogout() = isLogout

    fun onActivityDestroyed() {
        if (isLogout) {
            timerWatchDog?.refresh(Runnable {
                isLogout = false
                timerWatchDog = null
            })
        }
    }

    fun logout() {
        isLogout = true
        timerWatchDog = TimerWatchDog(500)
    }

    private class TimerWatchDog(private val delay: Long) : Runnable {

        private var timer: Timer? = null
        private var runnable: Runnable? = null

        fun refresh(runnable: Runnable) {
            this.runnable = runnable
            timer?.cancel()

            val timerTask = object : TimerTask() {
                override fun run() {
                    Thread(this@TimerWatchDog).start()
                }
            }
            timer = Timer()
            timer?.schedule(timerTask, delay)
        }

        override fun run() {
            runnable?.run()
        }
    }

}
```

**LogoutAwareActivity:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

abstract class LogoutAwareActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (LogoutHandler.isLogout()) {
            finish()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        LoginHandler.onActivityDestroyed()
    }

}
```

**A concrete Activity:**

```
class ActivityA : LogoutAwareActivity() {

    // ...
}
```

**Another concrete Activity:**

```
class ActivityB : LogoutAwareActivity() {

    // ...
}
```

**Your logout function:**

```
fun logout() {
    val intent = Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    LogoutHandler.logout()
    context.startActivity(intent)
}
```

**Visual Result:**

All of `MainActivity`, `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` and `ActivityC` are single instance.

Traversing between activities by pressing back button:

[image]

Going to `LoginActivity` then pressing back button:

[image]

Comment: you solution will not work. In your code event buss is unregestered in onStop. So all activities in backstack will no receive this event

Comment: the strange esenario you mentioned - is exactly my case)

Answer (score 3):

Before launching splash screen add this line

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this)
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what exactly you were trying to do but i got a feeling you could redesign your app differently to do it better.

Anyway to your question - I guess you can check onStart of the activities if the user has logged off, and if he did start a single instance launcher activity and close these activities with `finish()`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have several activities with launchMode SingleInstance. On log out i want to finish all activities and open launchScreen.

Here is one way:

1. Have all the activities extend a custom `BaseActivity`.
2. You can use [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager) to send local broadcast (within your app), when the logout button is clicked.
3. Inside the base activity you can implement the listener. You can call `finish()` inside the listener.
4. So when user clicks the logout button, you send the local broadcast to all the activities open. Since all your activities extend the common `BaseActivity`, the listener gets called and the activities finish.
5. After sending the broadcast, you can open the intended `LauncherActivity`.

See [How to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager) 
 for more.

P.S: You can un-register the listener in `onDestroy`. Since activity is still present, onDestroy won't have been called. And if it has already been destroyed then you have one less activity to worry about.

Comment: where do you unregisteer broadcastreceiver? onPause, onStop, onDestroy will be called prior i launch Logout activity.

Comment: Good question. You can do it inside the `onDestroy`. Since your activity's instance is still existing, I don't think onDestroy will be called. onStop will definitely be called since your new activity is completely hiding the old activities.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience extending the Application class is the simpler and most effective way to store limited amount of data which needs to be shared among all the activities.

In your case you can create a class holding your login data and store its instance in your custom Application object, where it can be reached by all activities. They can check for login availability at start, subscribe for changes and get notified when they need to finish. The Application object itself can subscribe for changes and start the login activity if needed.